# Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper Undkonsorten\Powermailpdf\ViewHelpers\Misc\VariablesViewHelper: mail

Tags: typo3, pdf-generation, typoscript, typo3-9.x, powermail

In TYPO3 9.5 using `powermail` with `powermailpdf` I'm getting the following error when submitting a form...

```
Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper Undkonsorten\Powermailpdf\ViewHelpers\Misc\VariablesViewHelper: mail.
```

It appears that it's complaining about *mail* but I don't know what to do about it. I've included the static templates for `powermail` followed by `powermailpdf` in the main TS template and see below for the mapping part of `powermailpdf`. I also added `{downloadLink}` in the RTE area for the receiver in the `powermail` content element and have email addresses entered there as well for the Receiver's Email and Sender's Email.

The only place I found the word *mail* in the docs was on **[this page](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermailpdf/stable/Administration/Index.html)**, but it appears I don't need to do that since I'm using a `powermail` version greater than 3 right?

*PS: I also posted this question as an [issue for `powermailpdf`](https://github.com/undkonsorten/powermailpdf/issues/14).*

### Relevant packages

- [typo3/cms-core](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-core) 9.5.31
- [templavoilaplus/templavoilaplus](https://packagist.org/packages/templavoilaplus/templavoilaplus) 7.3.6
- [in2code/powermail](https://packagist.org/packages/in2code/powermail) 6.2.0
- [undkonsorten/powermailpdf](https://packagist.org/packages/undkonsorten/powermailpdf) 2.4.5
- [tmw/fpdm](https://packagist.org/packages/tmw/fpdm) 2.9.2

### TypoScript I'm using

```
plugin.tx_powermailpdf {
    settings {
        enablePowermailPdf = 1
        showDownloadLink = 1
        email.attachFile = 1
        filelink {
            jumpurl = 1
            jumpurl.secure = 1
            jumpurl.secure.mimeTypes = pdf=application/pdf
            icon = 1
            icon_link = 1
        }
        sourceFile = EXT:rapidfyre_estreetdrivingschool/Resources/Public/Forms/Student_Training_Record.pdf
        fieldMap{
            # Note the format is... pdfField = PowermailField
            name = studentsname
            address = address
            city = city
            state = state
            zip = zip
            gender = gender
            home_number = homephone
            alternate_number = alternatephone
            student_cell = studentsphone
            student_email = studentsemail
            parent_name = parentsname
            parent_email = parentsemail
            high_school = highschool
            birth_date = dateofbirth
            permit_number = permitorid
            class = class

            # Hidden fields
            orientation = orientation
        }
    }
}
```

### Image of the first part of the error trace

[image: Error trace from powermailpdf after powermail form submission]

Answer (score 1):

EXT:powermailpdf is overriding this ViewHelper ([Code](https://github.com/undkonsorten/powermailpdf/blob/2.4.5/ext_typoscript_setup.txt)).

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        In2code\Powermail\ViewHelpers\Misc\VariablesViewHelper.className = Undkonsorten\Powermailpdf\ViewHelpers\Misc\VariablesViewHelper
    }
}
```

But the classes seems not match (in these versions):

- https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/6.2.0/Classes/ViewHelpers/Misc/VariablesViewHelper.php
- https://github.com/undkonsorten/powermailpdf/blob/2.4.5/Classes/ViewHelpers/Misc/VariablesViewHelper.php

So, a call of this VH (possibly also from the normal Powermail templates) will hit a non-compatible version of the ViewHelper.